# Pass a list of string's in IN clause in DocumentDb Query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

This query works when i try to fetch records using IN and multiple Email Id's:

```
var families = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<Restraunt>(_documentCollection.SelfLink,
"Select Restraunt.RestrauntId from Restraunt join Rest in Restraunt.Emails where Emails.Email IN ('abc@gmail.com','ab@gmail.com') ").AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

I want to know how can i pass a list of Email id's as a string in the query?
I tried passing the list of strings directly but is unable to resolve that. Is there any way out to do that?

Let's say i have

```
List<string> elist=new List<string>{"abc@gmail.com","b@gmail.com"}
```

How can i pass elist in the query?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your query to use ARRAY_CONTAINS instead, i.e. like this:

```
Select Restraunt.RestrauntId 
from Restraunt 
join Rest in Restraunt.Emails 
where ARRAY_CONTAINS(['abc@gmail.com','ab@gmail.com'], Emails.Email)
```

Then you can parameterize that query, and send the array of emails as a parameter.

Comment: int n = elist.Count(); string[] emailArray = new string[n]; emailArray = elist.ToArray(); Select Restraunt.RestrauntId from Restraunt join Rest in Restraunt.Emails where ARRAY_CONTAINS(emailArray, Emails.Email) I have passed the emailArray as a array but it shows error that "emailArray" is not resolved. –

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
List<string> elist=new List<string>{"abc@gmail.com","b@gmail.com"};

string emails = string.Empty;

if (eList!= null)
{
    emails = "'" + string.Join("','", eList.Select(x => x !=  String.Empty? x :"").Distinct().ToArray()) + "'";
    emails = emails.Replace("','','", "','");
}

var families = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<Restraunt>(_documentCollection.SelfLink,
    "Select Restraunt.RestrauntId FROM Restraunt join Rest in Restraunt.Emails 
     WHERE Emails.Email IN (" + emails + ") ").AsEnumerable().ToList();
```